# Google maps custom layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to color streets and roads based on my own set of latlng. I tried with Heatmaps but I don't like the result. I would like to get something like traffic layer... for example, a very long street may have different colors based on the density of my data... is there a way?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyword 'kml' or 'kmz' to search how to do this.